# Sql LIKE не работает

Tags: c#, mysql, like

```
SELECT
  n.title,
  n.preview_image,
  n.date,
  news_type.name
FROM news n 
  JOIN news_type 
  ON n.id_news = news_type.id 
WHERE news_type.name LIKE '%Аналитика%'
```

Этот запрос успешно работает в phpmyadmin в dbforge, но напрочь отказывается работать в с# коде. А именно ничего не возвращает. Если я удаляю `WHERE news_type.name LIKE '%Аналитика%'` то все работает. Я даже скопировал sql строку из дебага и вставил в phpmyadmin) Все равно не работает.

```
IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();

            string sql = String.Format("SELECT " +
                         "n.title, " +
                         "n.preview_image," +
                         "n.date," +
                         "news_type.name " +
                         "FROM news n " +
                         "JOIN news_type " +
                         "ON n.id_news = news_type.id "+
                         "WHERE news_type.name LIKE '%{0}%'","Аналитика");

            dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
            IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для корректной работы вам скорее всего нужно:

- проверить что у таблицы в базе выставлен collation utf8_general_ci
- в connection string указан utf-8 в качестве charset:

  ```
  "Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=test;Pwd=test;Charset=utf8;"
  ```